# How to prevent a site to show exit confirmation (the site is opened in a pop up from your site)?

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I have a php based website and I am making a site to open in a pop up and I need to open another site in the same pop up after a specific period of time (it is a kind of a website rotator).

It is working fine for most of the websites, but when a website opens which has an exit confirmation, the rotator stops as a dialog box opens, saying something like are you sure you want to leave this page?

Is there any way that i can make these website to work properly and redirect without opening any confirmation dialog box?

NOTE : The website (which is being rotated) owners are intentionally doing this to get more visitors. They are exploiting my rotator! The number of websites in the rotator are so high that I can't manually remove all those website as it will take ages to Check each website and removing the bad ones manually + more websites are added to the rotator by the users everyday.

The second thing that we can do is probably making a confirmation page that checks each website for exit confirmation dialog box and passes it only if there is no exit confirmation dialog box. The website will be added to the rotator only after passing from the confirmation page.

So can anyone share a script which checks for exit confirmation dialog box?

Comment: Yes, you can ask a site owner to remove that thing.

Comment: @zerkms - The website owner is intentionally doing this to get more visitors. they are exploiting my rotator! The number of website in the rotator are so high that i can't manually remove all those website!

Comment: @user1996782: add the item about popups to your terms of service and ask that owner to follow it, remove them if they don't follow your restrictions.

Comment: @zerkms - The problem is that the number of websites are so high that I can't remove all the websites manually. Checking each website and removing the bad ones manually will take ages!

Comment: @user1996782: you've chosen some weird way to earn money - you should have been prepared that people will try to cheat :-)

Comment: How are you changing the URL of the popup?

Comment: @Arjan - Probably yes. For example, initially the website opened in the pop up is a.com and after 1 minute I want website b.com to show up in the pop up.

Comment: I meant, for example: is your main page changing the URL of your popup? Or is your popup itself using some `<iframe>` in which the other sites are shown? Or anything else?

Comment: The main page changes the URL.

Comment: @zerkms - People will try to exploit everything!

Comment: Or create a preview image of the site every now and then, and show that, rather than the real site?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script. Use selenium for example, there you can check, wether a popup opens. If it opens, click it away, log the id of the page and go on. Every few ms a new site.

You can use EC2 or some other cloud service to host your checker. You can run multiple instances at the same time and after the first run you send an email to all the cheaters, they will be thrown out if they don't remove this.

And this can be automated too :-)

Comment: The cheaters will then probably return and add more such websites!

Comment: If you can please give me a script which will check if the page has an exit confirmation dialog box then i will make a confirmation page that each website will have to pass before it is added to the rotator.

Comment: No sorry. I have no selenium installed, but it is a fully equpped browser remote. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/ And a few more projects which might help: Behat and mink

Comment: @user, checking might be as easy as: change the URL, and then read back the URL after a short time? (Or close the popup and see if it did get closed?) But when doing it during registration, cheaters will simply disable the nagging (or quickly click OK) during the registration. So Fabian is right: you'd need to run such validations more than just once.

Comment: how can the checking be done automatically by the server such that the user will not have to do anything?

Comment: Selenium is a browser remote, s you can check wether a alert() oened an then let e browser clic ok. Sorry I can't explain all. If you want to achieve is, read the docs of selenim, behat and mink and begi coding :)

Comment: Still waiting for a better answer :(